# retain format of input file after using awk command

Tags: awk

I have a pdb file which looks like this-

```
ATOM   1737 HG13 VAL X 121      21.938  -9.234  -0.977  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1738  CG2 VAL X 121      21.679  -7.988   1.521  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1739 HG21 VAL X 121      22.611  -7.674   1.050  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1740 HG22 VAL X 121      21.340  -7.213   2.207  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1741 HG23 VAL X 121      21.863  -8.892   2.102  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1742  C   VAL X 121      19.373  -7.193  -1.494  1.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1743  O   VAL X 121      19.712  -7.180  -2.665  1.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1744  OXT VAL X 121      18.180  -7.240  -1.203  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1745  N   CYS X 122       3.096  -0.678 -19.522  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1746  H1  CYS X 122       2.977   0.322 -19.592  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1747  H2  CYS X 122       2.198  -1.101 -19.340  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1748  H3  CYS X 122       3.654  -0.993 -20.303  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1749  CZ  CYS X 122       3.913  -0.961 -18.319  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1750  HA  CYS X 122       3.361  -1.596 -17.626  0.00  0.00      SYST
```

I'm trying to change the 'X' to 'Y' in the 5th field whenever an 'OXT' is found on the 3rd field.
I have written the following using awk command-

```
awk '$3 == "OXT" {check=!check}check{sub(/X/,"Y",$5)}1' 1vwetest.pdb > 
1vwetestoutput.pdb
```

However this changes the formatting of my input file like this-

```
ATOM   1737 HG13 VAL X 121      21.938  -9.234  -0.977  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1738  CG2 VAL X 121      21.679  -7.988   1.521  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1739 HG21 VAL X 121      22.611  -7.674   1.050  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1740 HG22 VAL X 121      21.340  -7.213   2.207  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1741 HG23 VAL X 121      21.863  -8.892   2.102  0.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1742  C   VAL X 121      19.373  -7.193  -1.494  1.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM   1743  O   VAL X 121      19.712  -7.180  -2.665  1.00  0.00      SYST  
ATOM 1744 OXT VAL Y 121 18.180 -7.240 -1.203 0.00 0.00 SYST
ATOM 1745 N CYS Y 122 3.096 -0.678 -19.522 0.00 0.00 SYST
ATOM 1746 H1 CYS Y 122 2.977 0.322 -19.592 0.00 0.00 SYST
ATOM 1747 H2 CYS Y 122 2.198 -1.101 -19.340 0.00 0.00 SYST
ATOM 1748 H3 CYS Y 122 3.654 -0.993 -20.303 0.00 0.00 SYST
ATOM 1749 CZ CYS Y 122 3.913 -0.961 -18.319 0.00 0.00 SYST
ATOM 1750 HA CYS Y 122 3.361 -1.596 -17.626 0.00 0.00 SYST
```

How do I retain the column width after replacing the values? Or is there any other method to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` doesn't really care about the amount of whitespace, and neither should you.  Rather than trying to match the input precisely, perhaps just replace the record separator with a tab. eg:

```
awk '$3 == "OXT" {c=!c} {sub(/X/, c ? "Y" : "X",$5)}1' OFS='\t' input
```

The catch is that you need to modify each line in order to make the replacement happen, but that's not too much of an issue.

But in your case, it's also easy to just treat each individual character as a field and keep the whitespace precise with:

```
awk '$14$15$16 == "OXT" {c=!c} {sub(/X/, c ? "Y" : "X",$22)}1' FS= OFS= input
```

This won't work if the justification of the 3rd column shifts the OXT out of columns 14-16, but this may work for you.

Comment: This changes everything in column 5 to Y after the appearance of OXT in column 3

Comment: @HatLess Yes, it does.  Which seems to be what the OP wants.  But that detail is not particularly relevant to the question.

Comment: Indeed. However, the question seems to specify to change column 5 when column 3 contains `OXT`. I am somewhat discombobulated by OPs request.

Comment: If the desire is to only change the line in which OXT appears, these solutions become much simpler: `awk '{sub(/X/, $3 ~ /OXT/ ? "Y" : "X",$5)}1' OFS='\t'` and `awk '{sub(/X/,$14$15$16 == "OXT" ? "Y" : "X",$22)}1' FS= OFS=`

Comment: Should add it as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk`'s `match` function you can have substitution as well as keep the same spaces as they were there before it(written and tested with shown samples only).

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/na8pXr/1) for shown regex in this solution.

```
awk '
match($0,/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)([^[:space:]]+)([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)([^[:space:]]+)(.*)$/,arr){
  if(arr[2]=="OXT"){ arr[4]="Y" }
  print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3] arr[4] arr[5]
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for used regex:

```
^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+) ##Matching from starting of the value of line non-spaces(1 or more occurrences) followed by:
                                                      ##Spaces followed by 1 or more non-spaces followed by spaces.
                                                      ##Basically its capturing eg: (ATOM   1737 ) value here.
([^[:space:]]+)                                       ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has 1 or more non-spaces in it, this is the part which:
                                                      ##needs to be checked either its OXT or not as per requirement.
([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)               ##Creating 3rd capturing group where matching spaces followed by non-spaces followed by spaces
([^[:space:]]+)                                       ##Creating 4th capturing group which has non-capturing group. This contains values in it:
                                                      ##Which needs to be changed as per value in 2nd capturing group.
(.*)$                                                 ##Creating 5th capturing group which has everything else of value till end of line.
```

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU awk` and `FIELDWIDTHS` (assuming your input is fixed width as shown in the sample):

```bash
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='12 5 4 1 *' '$2==" OXT "{f=1} f{$4="Y"} {print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5}'
```

First field is 12 characters, second is 5 characters and so on. `*` means that you want to assign remaining characters to that field.

Note that I've used `f=1` instead of `f=!f` since you seem to want to change all `X` to `Y` once `OXT` is found.

Comment: This changes everything in column 5 to Y after the appearance of `OXT` in column 3

Comment: Yes, which is what OP seems to want based on their command attempted...

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` if applicable

```
$ sed -E 's/(([^ ]*( +|\t)){2}OXT ([^ ]*( +|\t)))X/\1Y/' input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you show from the input you show would just be the following, using any awk:

```
$ awk '$3=="OXT" { sub(/ X /," Y ") } 1' file
ATOM   1737 HG13 VAL X 121      21.938  -9.234  -0.977  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1738  CG2 VAL X 121      21.679  -7.988   1.521  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1739 HG21 VAL X 121      22.611  -7.674   1.050  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1740 HG22 VAL X 121      21.340  -7.213   2.207  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1741 HG23 VAL X 121      21.863  -8.892   2.102  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1742  C   VAL X 121      19.373  -7.193  -1.494  1.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1743  O   VAL X 121      19.712  -7.180  -2.665  1.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1744  OXT VAL Y 121      18.180  -7.240  -1.203  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1745  N   CYS X 122       3.096  -0.678 -19.522  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1746  H1  CYS X 122       2.977   0.322 -19.592  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1747  H2  CYS X 122       2.198  -1.101 -19.340  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1748  H3  CYS X 122       3.654  -0.993 -20.303  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1749  CZ  CYS X 122       3.913  -0.961 -18.319  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1750  HA  CYS X 122       3.361  -1.596 -17.626  0.00  0.00      SYST
```

or if you need to handle other situations than you show in your example then this might be what you need, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\S/\s` shorthand:

```
$ awk '($3=="OXT") && match($0,/((\S+\s+){4}).(.*)/,a) { $0=a[1] "Y" a[3] } 1' file
ATOM   1737 HG13 VAL X 121      21.938  -9.234  -0.977  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1738  CG2 VAL X 121      21.679  -7.988   1.521  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1739 HG21 VAL X 121      22.611  -7.674   1.050  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1740 HG22 VAL X 121      21.340  -7.213   2.207  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1741 HG23 VAL X 121      21.863  -8.892   2.102  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1742  C   VAL X 121      19.373  -7.193  -1.494  1.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1743  O   VAL X 121      19.712  -7.180  -2.665  1.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1744  OXT VAL Y 121      18.180  -7.240  -1.203  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1745  N   CYS X 122       3.096  -0.678 -19.522  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1746  H1  CYS X 122       2.977   0.322 -19.592  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1747  H2  CYS X 122       2.198  -1.101 -19.340  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1748  H3  CYS X 122       3.654  -0.993 -20.303  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1749  CZ  CYS X 122       3.913  -0.961 -18.319  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1750  HA  CYS X 122       3.361  -1.596 -17.626  0.00  0.00      SYST
```

or using any POSIX awk and assuming the spaces between fields are blanks because if they were tabs then we wouldn't need to do any of this:

```
$ awk '($3=="OXT") && match($0,/([^ ]+ +){4}/) { $0=substr($0,1,RLENGTH) "Y" substr($0,RLENGTH+2) } 1' file
ATOM   1737 HG13 VAL X 121      21.938  -9.234  -0.977  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1738  CG2 VAL X 121      21.679  -7.988   1.521  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1739 HG21 VAL X 121      22.611  -7.674   1.050  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1740 HG22 VAL X 121      21.340  -7.213   2.207  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1741 HG23 VAL X 121      21.863  -8.892   2.102  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1742  C   VAL X 121      19.373  -7.193  -1.494  1.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1743  O   VAL X 121      19.712  -7.180  -2.665  1.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1744  OXT VAL Y 121      18.180  -7.240  -1.203  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1745  N   CYS X 122       3.096  -0.678 -19.522  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1746  H1  CYS X 122       2.977   0.322 -19.592  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1747  H2  CYS X 122       2.198  -1.101 -19.340  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1748  H3  CYS X 122       3.654  -0.993 -20.303  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1749  CZ  CYS X 122       3.913  -0.961 -18.319  0.00  0.00      SYST
ATOM   1750  HA  CYS X 122       3.361  -1.596 -17.626  0.00  0.00      SYST
```

Just change `[^ ]+ +` to `[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+` in the POSIX version if there could be tabs present, the gawk version would already handle them.